# Dynamodb number type removing 0s on decimal point?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I am experimenting with the number type on Dynamo DB. I want a double/floating point representation. I have the following:

```
{
    "a": {
        "N": 1.25
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{ "a": 1.25 }
```

this is expected I think. However when I try the following:

```
{
    "b": {
        "N": 1.0
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
{ "b": 1 }
```

Why are the .0 removed? I understand that 1 and 1.0 are really the same, but I really would like a decimal representation. Is there a way where I can get a decimal representation of number types for 0s decimal points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This is expected](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.NamingRulesDataTypes.html#HowItWorks.DataTypes.Scalar):

> In DynamoDB, numbers are represented as variable length. Leading and trailing zeroes are trimmed.

If you need to keep the precision, consider storing it as a String value.